# BuildConfig is public, should be declared in a file named BuildConfig.java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, build

Seem to be getting this occurring error whenever I run my android application.

The only way to get around it is by rebuilding the project and runs normally again.

If anyone knows the reason for this will be much appreciated

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13811020/error-class-x-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-x-java

Answer (score 9):

Try
Build -> Clean Project
Then
Build -> Make Project

Comment: this answer solved my issue but when i get every build error ,i always get again same issue. can i find permanent answer?

Comment: **GREAT answer, it worked!**
After upgrading to Android Studio Arctic Fox, I kept getting this problem and couldn't figure out how to solve the problem.
Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue when ever tried to install the App,

```
Build -> Clean Project Then Build -> Make Project
```

even though problem arises again and again then go with the below steps.

```
Delete .gradle Folder within android Directory
```

Now, click Run it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

For Flutter users,

1. Execute Flutter Clean in terminal of your project folder.
2. Run flutter pub get to get all packages.
3. Run your project.

Although, the problem arises everytime I try to run the project. This problems arises after I added a package in my project. So, that package might be causing some problem.

Answer (score 0):

Under your Project view in Android Studio navigate to the `.gradle` folder.

In that folder, if you see more than one version of gradle, such as, for example, 7.0.2 and 6.1.0.

Delete one of the versions, preferably the lower version.

Clean, build, and you run.

It should run each time without the error, or the necessity to clean and build.