# How do I declare BuildConfig file in Android Studio?

Tags: android, error-handling

when I run my project in android studio every time I have this error. As you know BuildConfig is in Build file which we shouldn't edit. What should I do ?

```
class BuildConfig is public, should be declared in a file named BuildConfig.java
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BuildConfig is public, should be declared in a file named BuildConfig.java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59438157/buildconfig-is-public-should-be-declared-in-a-file-named-buildconfig-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see you have BuildConfig file or not. It should be here:
[image]

And in that file this code is written.

```
  public final class BuildConfig {
  public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
  public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.example.mytestapplication";
  public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
  public static final String FLAVOR = "";
  public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
  public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
}
```

As you said it can't be edited.

Comment: I checked the file was duplicated then I deleted to copy it works fine thank you